# Unable to set div's background to linear gradient using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a dynamic `div` element with styles including linear gradient. It should be displayed dynamically with a button, but the gradient does not get added.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("btn");
x.addEventListener("click", addbox);
   
function addbox() {
  var y = document.createElement("Div");
  y.id = "div1";
  y.style.border = "1px";
  y.style.borderRadius = "20px";
  y.style.height = "200px";
  y.style.width = "500px"; 
  y.style.backgroundImage = "linearGradient(to bottom right, yellow , cyan)";
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(y);
}
```

```css
#btn {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="addbox()"> CLICK ME TO DISPLAY </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of little mistakes but here is something that works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> ADD BOX ON CLICK FUNCTION </title>
    <style>
        #btn {
            height: 50px;
            width: 150px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

        function addbox() {
            var y = document.createElement("Div");
            y.id = "div1";
            y.style.border = "1px";
            y.style.borderRadius = "20px";
            y.style.height = "200px";
            y.style.width = "500px";
            y.style.background = "linear-gradient(to bottom right, yellow , cyan)";
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(y);
        }

        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
            var x = document.getElementById("btn");
            x.addEventListener("click", addbox);
        });

    </script>
    <button id="btn"> CLICK ME TO DISPLAY </button>
</body>

</html>
```

1. Your `document.getElementById("btn")` cannot work before the page has finished loading, so you have to put this inside a `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` event that will fire only when your div is there
2. Remove the `onclick="addbox()"` from the div because it would fire twice per click
3. `linearGradient` spelling is wrong. It's `linear-gradient`
4. The property to apply the linear gradient is not `y.style.backgroundImage` but `y.style.background`

Comment: Hey @Vincent How can I display it horizontally?

Comment: @SID you mean yellow on the left and cyan on the right? Just use "to right" instead of "to bottom right"

Comment: No @Vincent, I meant to display the div element itself horizontally instead of displaying it vertically one on top of another!